# Installed PWA is not updating

Tags: progressive-web-apps, quasar-framework

I have developed a PWA using Quasar framework. I didn't change anything in service-worker or manifest file, just going with defaults. 
I have hosted the build on AWS S3 facing a cloud-front distribution. 
When I push the updated build on S3 and invalidate the cloud-front distribution cache. The user who opens the website via browser gets an updated version. but users with installed PWA never get the updates unless they open the website again in the browser. 
I have planned to update changes every other day. what is the best way that whenever I push change installed PWA gets updated instantly?

Comment: That is the default way it should work. When the installed PWA is opened it loads from the Cache. Changes are loaded in the background. Next time the user opens the PWA they should see the changes. If you want them to instantly load all changes you will need to add extra code to notify your users to get the updated version.

Comment: My problem is users never get an update unless they open browser and refresh the page. if users keep using installed app (PWA) they never get an update. i have tried to refresh every now and then for more than 24 hours to see if changes are updated with no luck.

Comment: Refresh does not work, but closing the app then opening does? I believe that is the default way it works. You will need to add extra code to notify your users (who do not close the app) to get the updated version.